# Export Google sheet as xlsx to company network drive

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This function is triggered when the sheet is changed.

```
function exportAsxlsx() {
 var spreadsheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId()
 var file          = Drive.Files.get(spreadsheetId);
 var url           = file.exportLinks[MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL];
 var token         = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
 var response      = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
   headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
 }
});

 var blobs   = response.getBlob();
 var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('\\GBC1234.fs1.util.xxint.com\Shared\Projects\Test_Google2Excel');
 if(folder.hasNext()) {
   var existingPlan1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName('TestGoogle2Excel.xlsx');
   if(existingPlan1.hasNext()){
     var existingPlan2 = existingPlan1.next();
     var existingPlanID = existingPlan2.getId();
     Drive.Files.remove(existingPlanID);
   }
 } else {
folder = DriveApp.createFolder('\\GBC1234.fs1.util.xxint.com\Shared\Projects\Test_Google2Excel');
}
folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('\\GBC1234.fs1.util.xxint.com\Shared\Projects\Test_Google2Excel').next();
folder.createFile(blobs).setName('TestGoogle2Excel.xlsx')
  }
```

What happens is that it makes the directory "\GBC1234.fs1.util.xxint.com\Shared\Projects\Test_Google2Excel" in Google drive then saves the file there.

How can I get it to save to our company drive?

Comment: Google Apps Script is not able to save files to a "company drive". You should use something else.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a locally hosted 'client' which downloads said file from the known drive location to the network.

Once you start thinking about this the client could interact with a number of points on the workflow you describe.

I.e.
 1. As described, polls google drive to see if output xlsx is created and download. Drive API
 2. Poll the sheet in drive itself and also then trigger the apps script to perform conversion. Apps Script Execution API
 3. Skip those altogether and interact with the sheet directly. Sheets API

In each case you'll want to cache a checksum of the original sheet data to only act if things have changed. (There are a number of ways to do this)